# LaTeX: Redefining the citation macro temporarily

Tags: latex

I'm new to latex, but it seems you can temporarily redefine some commands? The problem I have is that normally the citation is (SMITH, 2000). But at times, I'd like to have Smith (2000) instead. Anyway I can temporarily redefine it, then use the standard version again after that "block" of code?

Comment: You may get quicker and better answers at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enclose the local definition in braces ({}).

```
\newcommand\foo{FOO!}
\foo
{\renewcommand\foo{BAR?}\foo\foo}
\foo
```

This will generate something like:

```
FOO!BAR?BAR? FOO!
```

This can be done inside macro definitions, too - just make sure you add the extra braces:

```
\newcommand\newfoo{{\renewcommand\foo{BAR?}\foo}}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent suggestion to include the braces inside `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 1):

You should already have `\citep` and `\citet` commands that should do what you want, there's no reason to redefine the macros yourself.